# JSlider -- differentiate between setValue() and user input

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm trying to have a JSlider that increments every second or so, based on the playhead of a MediaPlayer (from another class which sets the value of the static JSlider). For example,

```
Window.timeSlider/*static JSlider from other class*/.setValue(/*int current progress of the audio clip*/);
```

It acts as a timeline for an audio file. It calls this about every second. However, I want to detect separately the user input -- when the user drags the slider manually -- from the incremental changes being done from the other class. I ran into this issue when I tried to use the action listener for the slider:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == timeSlider) {
        JSlider src = (JSlider)e.getSource();

        if (!src.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            timeSliderChanged = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the getValueIsAdjusting() is true when the user changes the slider, *as well as* when the slider increments. This means I can't adjust the clip to the user-specified time, and the slider simply jumps back to its original position when I release it.

Any way to distinguish when the method is changing the slider and when the user is?

Comment: I had better luck using a `JProgressBar` with a `MouseListener`..

Answer (score 1):

Keep a private field that indicates a programmatic change:

```
private boolean programmaticallyChangingSlider;

// ...

    programmaticallyChangingSlider = true;

    slider.setValue(newValue);

    EventQueue.invokeLater(
        () -> { programmaticallyChangingSlider = false; });
```

The ChangeListener can then check that field:

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == timeSlider) {
        if (!programmaticallyChangingSlider) {
            // Respond to user input here
        }
    }
}
```